ClientClosedError: The client is closed.. Redis Error
const redis = require('redis');

const CHANNEL = {
  TEST: 'TEST',
};

class PubSub {
  constructor() {
    this.publisher = redis.createClient()
    this.subscriber = redis.createClient();

    this.subscriber.subscribe(CHANNEL.TEST);

    this.subscriber.on('message', (channel, message) => this.handleMessage(channel, message)).connect();
  }

  handleMessage(channel, message) {
    console.log(`message received channel : ${channel} message ${message}`);
  }
}

const checkpubsub = new PubSub();

setTimeout(() => checkpubsub.publisher.publish(CHANNEL.TEST, 'hello'), 1000);

now when i try to access run this file then showing this error.. this code is basic code of redis server connection and now i try to connect publisher and subscriber such as youtube channel.. publisher post video and then subscriber get notification
ClientClosedError: The client is closed

so please solve this error
